# Issue with fetch in ROracle

Tags: sql, r, plsql, oracle10g, r-dbi

I am having issues on retrieving a large amount of data using ROracle (I have read-only rights on the Oracle database)
As the data involved exceeds > 4 gigs I am not able to use the dbGetQuery from ROracle that works perfectly.

Instead I am trying to use the dbSendQuery + fetch but it seems not working with Oracle. (It works perfectly with RmySQL package)

For example :

With my Oracle version:

```
dbGetQuery(con2, "select * from PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION")
                              PRODUCT    VERSION     STATUS
                              NLSRTL  10.2.0.3.0 Production
  Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition  10.2.0.3.0       Prod
                              PL/SQL  10.2.0.3.0 Production
             TNS for 32-bit Windows:  10.2.0.3.0 Production
```

if I try:

```
query <- "SELECT * FROM BFMXML_SUIVI"
rs <- dbSendQuery(con2, query, bulk_read = 10000L, prefetch = T)
test <- fetch(rs, n = 10)
dim(test)
```

[1]  1 13

```
dbGetRowCount(rs)
```

[1] 1

But I would expect to get 10 rows...

Then fetching again:

```
test <- fetch(rs, n = 10)
dim(test)
```

[1]  1 13

```
dbGetRowCount(rs)
```

[1] 1

Hence, the next row was not fetched and looking at the result of 'test', I can see it is filled in with zeros only (which is not right + it was not the case with the first fetch call)

Do you see any alternative / solution?

Answer (score 0):

Quick ones, and I should add that I have no Oracle backend handy to test this:

1. I much prefer a single `res <- dbGetQuery(con, query)` call over the `dbSendQuery()` and `fetch()` combination.
2. I recall prior discussions on the r-sig-db list where it was stated that some backends 'lie' about the amount of data being ready to be retrieved, using `n = -1` was often offered as a fix.  However that may have been in the context of `RODBC`.

Comment: I do use dbGetQuery when I can (it works perfectly with Oracle) but the issue is that it will load the whole SQL table within R. Thus, if you have limited memory size for R (which is my case!) you get a memory allocation error. That's why I would like to use dbSendQuery to load the data bit by bit and summarize it within R